# updateOne method not updating model, instead throw an error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm updating a model inside an if condition but model not updating

```
exports.check_verification = (req, res) => {
var verifyCode=req.body.code;
console.log(vcode);
if(verifyCode=vcode){
  const veryfy=User.updateOne({ _id:req.body.user_id }, { $set: { verify_status:"Registered"} },)
  Promise.all([veryfy]).then(() => {
    res.send("success");
  }).catch((err) =>{
    console.log(err);
  })
  
}else{
  console.log("fail");
  res.send("fail");
}}
```

throw an error like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message `req.body.user_id` is not a string but instead is an object holding:

`{ code: '...', user_id: '...' }`

So what you can do is :

```
User.updateOne({ _id:req.body.user_id.user_id } //...
```

There might be something wrong with your request-model though.